# How can I find files in directories listed in a file?

Tags: bash, find, directory-structure

In a directory there are several subdirectories, something like:

```
TopLevelDir
+-- SubDir1
+-- SubDir2
+-- SubDir3
+-- SubDir4
+-- SubDir5
+-- SubDir6
```

I need to find files containing some specific text in a specific subset of those subdirectories. What is needed can be accomplished with:

```
find SubDir1 SubDir2 SubDir4 -type f -exec grep -H "desired text" {} \;
```

A similar search will be needed frequently. To save time and typing, I would like to store the names of the subdirectories to be searched in a file and use that when I run the find command next time, something like:

```
find subdirs2search.txt -type f  -name="*.txt" -exec grep -H "desired text" {} \;
```

Searching the web, checking man pages, and even checking my *nix book hasn't turned up anything on how to do this.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: If you used `+` to end the `-exec` instead of `\;`, you wouldn't need the `-H` option on the grep command (it's the default if multiple file args are used).   More importantly, it would also run noticeably faster because it wouldn't need to fork one grep per file (instead it would run grep with as many filename args as will fit on the command line).    `find SubDir1 SubDir2 SubDir4 -type f -exec grep "desired text" {} +`

Comment: @cas: it's possible that `find` only finds 1 regular file total, so `-H` is still a good idea.  But yes, `-exec ... {} +` is *much* faster than `\;` especially for lots of small files where startup overhead matters more.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, that's true. i didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 9):

If the directory names are one-per-line, then you could avoid issues with directories that have spaces or tabs or wildcard characters in their names by using `readarray` (bash v4+):

```
readarray -t dirs < subdirs2search.txt
find "${dirs[@]}" ...
```

That would still not help if some directory names start with `-`, but with GNU `find`, there's no way around that.

Comment: Prepending `./` to relative paths would ensure they're not parsed as options.

Comment: @John, unless they are full paths already (starting with `/`)

Answer (score 5):

Naturally, posting the question helped snap me out of my fixation on doing this strictly with `find` and made me think of expanding the file via Bash. I'm posting an answer hoping it will help someone else (and also to document this for my own future use).

The incantation for having Bash expand the file contents is `$(<subdirs2search.txt)`. So, if subdirs2search.txt contains:

```
SubDir1 SubDir2 SubDir4
```

A command like the following will accomplish the desired search:

```
find $(<subdirs2search.txt) -type f -name="*.txt" -exec grep -H "desired text" {} \;
```

Comment: Note that it's not specific to `bash`. The `$(<file)` operator comes from ksh and is also supported by  zsh. In other POSIX-like shells, you can use `$(cat file)` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for the input. That said, I've rolled back to my original answer. Testing your solution, I found that it didn't limit the search to only text files, and it ran significantly slower. Also, it is different enough that - IMO - you should submit it as your own answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Are you possibly on macOS or FreeBSD where `-r` still follows symlinks? You can add `-D skip` to skip fifo/devices/sockets. See also [Recursive grep vs find / -type f -exec grep {} \; Which is more efficient/faster?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131535)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The system in questiion is running a clone of Red Hat.

Comment: "I found that it didn't limit the search to only text files", to be fair, neither does your `find` command.

Comment: @muru and Matt: `ack` is often a handy tool for recursive-grep type stuff.  It *does* by default limit searching to text files.  https://beyondgrep.com/.  It's packed by most GNU/Linux distros.  e.g. `ack "desired text"  $(<subdirs.txt)` should probably do what you want and is very easy to type.  Plus it does nice color output for interactive use.

Comment: @muru: Yes, but I guess what I really care about is that the solution that Stéphane Chazelas suggested returned messages about searching for text in a binary file, but my `find ... -exec grep ...` command does not.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for the suggestion. However, that's not installed on my (work) system and I don't have the privilege to do so (and getting it installed is a battle I choose not to fight).

Comment: In that case, some of the directories listed in that file are almost certainly links, and your `find` command isn't traversing them, so you're probably missing out on some results.

Comment: @muru: Well no, because I had other options filtering the results. Perhaps there is a way to do that using grep the way Stephane suggests, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: In that case you should show the other options as well. As it stands, the find command in your answer the grep added by Stéphane are largely the same, except the grep will perform better.

Comment: @muru: Other option added to q & a.

Comment: With grep, that's `--include='*.txt'`

Comment: @GreenMatt: It's basically just a perl script, you don't need any privileges to install it for your own use from upstream, not the RPM package.  If you can't even put it in any directory in your `$PATH` or modify your own `$PATH` to include your `$HOME/bin`, you can put it anywhere and `alias ack=perl ~/somewhere/ack.pl`.

Answer (score 5):

> I found that it didn't limit the search to only text files

`ack` is often a handy tool for recursive-grep type stuff.  It *does* by default limit searching to text files (determined using heuristics based on file name and content) and will by default skip directories like `.git`/`.svn` which if you're a developer is likely what you want.  https://beyondgrep.com/.

It's packed by most GNU/Linux distros so it's easy to install.  It's written in perl (so its regexps are `perl` regexps, similar to those of GNU `grep -P`).

```
ack -- "desired text"  $(<subdirs.txt)
```

should probably do what you want and is very easy to type.  Plus it does nice color output for interactive use.

(Different ways of word-splitting `subdirs.txt` onto a command line are covered in other answers.  You might want to just let the shell's standard word-splitting do it, or `readarray` to split only on lines and also block glob expansion.)

Comment: Not the it only properly works with ASCII/ISO8859-1 data (not non-ASCII UTF-8 characters, even with `PERL_UNICODE=SLAD` which seems to only work for its `--filter`)

Comment: `PERLIO=':utf8' PERL_UNICODE=A  ack 'utf8 text'` helps (though makes it significantly slower and reports decoding errors for non-UTF-8 input).

Answer (score 3):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use File::Find ();

sub wanted;
sub process_file ($@);

my $dirfile = shift;    # First argument is the filename containing the list
                        # of directories.

my $pattern = shift;    # Second arg is a perl RE containing the pattern to search
                        # for. Remember to single-quote it on the command line.

# Read in the @dirs array from $dirfile
#
# A NUL-separated file is best, just in case any of the directory names
# contained line-feeds.  If you're certain that could never happen, a
# plain-text LF-separated file would do.
#
# BTW, you can easily generate a NUL-separated file from the shell with:
#    printf "%s\0" dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 $'dir\nwith\n3\nLFs' > dirs.txt

my @dirs=();

{
  local $/="\0";    # delete this line if you want to use a LF-separated file.
                    # In that case, the { ... } block around the code from open to
                    # close is no longer needed.  It's only there so it's possible
                    # to make a local change to the $/ aka $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
                    # variable.

  open(DIRFILE,"<",$dirfile);
  while(<DIRFILE>) {
    chomp;
    push @dirs, $_;
  };
  close(DIRFILE);
};

File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, @dirs);
exit;

sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) && -f _ && process_file($_);
}

sub process_file ($@) {

    # This function currently just greps for pattern in the filename passed to
    # it. As the function name implies, it could be used to process the file
    # in any way, not just grep it.

    my $filename = shift;

    # uncomment the return statement below to skip "binary" files.
    # (note this is a workable but fairly crude test.  Perl's File::MMagic
    # module can be used to more accurately identify file types, using the
    # same "magic" file databases as the /usr/bin/file command)

    # return if -B $filename;

    open(FILE,"<",$filename);
    while(<FILE>) {
      print "$filename:$_" if (m/$pattern/o) ;
    };

    close(FILE);
}
```

This uses `perl` and perl's `File::Find` module to do the same thing as your `find ... -exec grep`.

There's nothing particularly interesting or special about this script **except** that the `process_file` function can be very easily modified to do anything you want with or to the file - e.g. change owner or perms, delete it, rename it, insert or delete lines or whatever else you might want.

e.g. if you wanted to delete files which contain text matching the pattern, you could replace the process_file function with something like this:

```perl
sub process_file ($@) {

    my $filename = shift;
    my $found = 0;

    # uncomment to skip "binary" files:
    return if -B $filename;

    open(FILE,"<",$filename);
    while(<FILE>) {
      if (m/$pattern/o) {
        $found = 1;
        last;
      };
    };

    close(FILE);
    unlink $filename if ($found);
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that the `wanted` function in this script is currently only looking for regular files (the `-f` test).   Perl's `stat` and `lstat` functions provide access to all of the file metadata that `find` can use to match files (uid, gid, perms, size, atime, mtime, etc) so the `wanted` function can replicate ANY and all find predicates.   see `perldoc -f stat` and `perldoc -f lstat` for details.

BTW, the script was generated initially by `find2perl`, and then modified substantially to a) read in the list of directories from a file, and b) to do the grep in perl code rather than by forking `grep` and c) add a lot of comments.  Performance should be nearly identical to `find ... -exec grep` because grep can't open files or do a regexp pattern match significantly faster than perl can.  It may even be faster.

Also BTW, `find2perl` used to be included with perl, but since perl 5.22 it was removed and can now be found on CPAN at [find2perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-find2perl/script/find2perl)

Answer (score 3):

Another tool similar to `ack` (Peter Cordes's answer) is [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) or `rg`. It supports the same usage:

```
rg -- "desired text" $(<subdirs2search.txt)
```

It also skips binary files by default.