# How to use find with paths that are listed in a file while ensuring that spaces are taken care of?

Tags: find, xargs

I have a list of paths that are in a file called `pathlist.txt`. It looks like so:

```
/home/abc/dirA
/home/abc/dirB
/home/abc/dir with space
/home/abc/dirX
```

I need to find all files in each of those paths. The following approach works but only with paths that do not have spaces in them:

`find $(tr '\n' ' ' < pathlist.txt) -type f -printf "%p, %AY-%Am-%Ad \n"`

I tried setting `IFS=$'\n'` and some experimentation with `xargs` but no success. Any suggestions as to how to make sure that find accepts paths that have spaces (and possibly other special chars) in them?

Comment: Related: [How can I find files in directories listed in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535637/65304)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `bash`, one way is:

```
readarray -t a < pathlist.txt
find "${a[@]}" -type f ....
```

Answer (score 3):

The `readarray` approach is the simplest, but if you are using a shell that doesn't support it, you can try the following instead which should work on any POSIX shell:

```
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    find "$pathname" -type f
done < pathlist.txt
```

Comment: Or `set --; while IFS= read -r p; do set -- "$@" "$p"; done <pathlist.txt; find "$@" -type f`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the GNU implementation of xargs, you can use the `-d` option to set the delimiter, in this case to a newline.

Demo:

```bsh
xargs -d '\n' -I{} printf '<<%s>>\n' '{}' <<END
abc def
unix and linux
END
```

```
<<abc def>>
<<unix and linux>>
```

So a first stab at your command would be

```bsh
xargs -a pathlist.txt -d '\n' -I{} -- \
   find '{}' -type f -printf "%p, %AY-%Am-%Ad \n"
```

There are two problems with this:

- It will now run several `find` instances, as `xargs -I` replacement implies `-L1`.
- You'll still have problems with file names which contain newlines.

You could solve the first problem by using GNU `printf %q` to produce strings that are escaped for shell:

```bsh
find $(xargs -a pathlist.txt -d '\n' printf '%q\n') \
    -type f -printf "%p, %AY-%Am-%Ad \n"
```

For the second one, consider  separating with `\0` instead, and using `xargs -0` to use that as delimiter.